# swift generic and dynamic method dispatch

Tags: swift, generics, dynamic

I create an extension for UITableViewCell, and give the default method.
Through the `set<T: UITableViewCell>` method, I want the `setupData` method can dynamic dispatch by the cell type. But it always failed, and the result jump to the fatalError.

```
import UIKit

class cell: UITableViewCell {
    func setupData<T>(_ data: T) {
        print(#function)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        set(cell.self)
    }

    func set<T: UITableViewCell>(_ t: T.Type) {
        let cell = T()
        cell.setupData(1)
    }
}

protocol Action {
    func setupData<T>(_ data: T)
}

extension Action {
    func setupData<T>(_ data: T) {
        fatalError("This method is abstract, need subclass.")
    }
}

extension UITableViewCell: Action {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Things in an extension are always statically dispatched. In `set`, `cell.setupData(1)` is already bound to the implementation in the extension at compile time.

I don't see why you would need this extension anyway, you only need:

```
class cell: UITableViewCell, Action {
    func setupData<T>(_ data: T) {
        print(#function)
    }
}

protocol Action {
    func setupData<T>(_ data: T)
    init()
}

...

func set<T: Action>(_ t: T.Type) {
    let cell = T()
    cell.setupData(1)
}
```

Comment: I want to limit the cell set data entry and the cell don't need conforming the Action. So, I just need code `cell.setupData` in my wrapper。Thanks ~

Comment: @钱嘘嘘 Did my answer answer your question or not? If so, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!