# Swift generic protocol issue

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I am having a strange issue while implementing Swift generic protocol. 
Please refer to this playground code snippet.

```
import Foundation

protocol FooProtocol {
    static func foo() -> String
}

struct Outer<T: FooProtocol>: FooProtocol {
    static func foo() -> String {
        return T.foo()
    }
}

struct Inner<T>: FooProtocol {
    static func foo() -> String {
        return "default. T is \(T.self)"
    }
}

extension Inner where T == String {
    static func foo() -> String {
        return "Inner String"
    }
}

extension Inner where T == Int {
    static func foo() -> String {
        return "Inner Int"
    }
}

print(Inner<Int>.foo())
print(Outer<Inner<Int>>.foo())

print(Inner<String>.foo())
print(Outer<Inner<String>>.foo())
```

The result of this is

```
Inner Int
default. T is Int
Inner String
default. T is String
```

The result I expected is:

```
Inner Int
Inner Int
Inner String
Inner String
```

What bothers me is that `Inner` struct totally works. It runs into default implementation when it is contained in `Outer` struct. Can anyone explain this?
Also, is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do here?

Comment: @Sweeper I just edited my post. I don't expect default foo() implementation since I defined Int and String case specifically.

Comment: Pretty sure this is impossible, reason being that methods in extensions are statically dispatched. Can't find any documentation saying that though, only from my personal experience.

Comment: @sweeper If thats the case. Why is Inner<Int>.foo() working fine?

Comment: do you understand what is meant by “static dispatch”?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56413484/swift-generic-and-dynamic-method-dispatch/56413572#56413572) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280827/how-to-implement-a-swift-protocol-across-structs-with-conflicting-property-names/58280971#58280971) where I mentioned this. In the comment section of the second post, I also included some other links that talk about static dispatch.